# scenekit, how to bend an object

Tags: 3d, scenekit

I'm new to 3D.

I have a straight stick object which is a SCNBox, and at some stage I want to bend it (with animation). Is there any way to achieve this? Or do I have to use multiple objects to simulate a SCNBox in the first place, and then move and rotate those objects to simulate bending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SCNBox` has a `heightSegmentCount` property that you can use to produce more vertices.

Using a shader modifier you'll be able to bend the cube. That's how the grass blades are animated in [Fox: Building a SceneKit Game with the Xcode Scene Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Fox). This can be done right in the SceneKit editor see ([Enhancements to SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-606/) from WWDC 2015) or programmatically.

**edit:**

Here is the modifier for the `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry` entry point:

```
float offset = _geometry.color.x * (sin(1.2 * u_time + (_geometry.position.x + _geometry.position.z) * 4.0) + 0.5) * 0.02;
_geometry.position.x += offset;
_geometry.color.xyz = vec3(1.0);
```

Bending weights are baked in the vertex color (`SCNGeometrySourceSemanticColor`, but you could also use texture coordinates) which is later reset to `1.0` so that they doesn't affect the final color of the geometry.

Comment: Is this a geometry shader modifier?

Comment: There should be a moral law against using the word "shader" without the contextualisation of its type and explicit clarification of that which it's operating upon ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options, depending on what effect you're after. I don't think you'll be able to do it with just a single `SCNBox`, though.

You can design your object in a 3D tool like Blender, Maya, or Cheetah3D. Create an animation within that tool, export the model to Collada/DAE format, and display it in SceneKit. You can then play the animation by name.

You might also be able to use the morphing API. That's slide 34 of the [WWDC 2014 SceneKit sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitWWDC2014/Introduction/Intro.html). The live session is [Session 610](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-610/).

Inverse Kinematics could work for you if you want the end of your stick to touch a particular point. That would involve building IK into your Collada file, or constructing the object programmatically using physics joints.

None of these approaches are beginner-level techniques.