# Drawing a 3D arc and helix in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

A recent question here made me think of SceneKit again, and I remembered a problem I never solved.

My app displays antenna designs using SK. Most antennas use metal rods and mesh reflectors so I used SCNCylinder for the rods, SCNPlane for the reflector and SCNFloor for the ground. The whole thing took a couple of hours, and I'm *utterly* noob at 3D.

But some antennas use wires bent into arcs or helixes, and I punted here and made crappy segmented objects using several cylinders end-to-end. It looks ass-tastic.

Ideally I would like a single object that renders the arc or helix with a cylindrical cross section. Basically SCNTorus, but with a start and end angle.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353598/scenekit-draw-3d-parabola) talks about using a UIBezierPath in SK, but it uses `extrude` to produce a ribbon-like shape. Is there a way to do something similar but with a cylinder cross section (like a partial SCNTorus)?

I know I can make a custom shape by creating the vertexes (and normals and such) but I'm hoping I missed a simpler solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An arc you can do with `SCNShape`. Start with the technique from my other answer to get an extruded, ribbon-like arc. You'll want to make sure that the part where your path traces back on itself is offset by a distance the same as your extrusion depth, so you end up with a shape that's square in cross section.

To make it circular in cross section, use the [`chamferProfile`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshape/1522865-chamferprofile) property — give it a path that's a quarter circle, and set the chamfer radius equal to half the extrusion depth, and the four quarter-circle chamfers will meet, forming a circular cross section.

A helix is another story. `SCNShape` takes a planar path — one that varies in only two dimensions — and extrudes it to make a three-dimensional solid. A helix is a path that varies in three dimensions to start with. SceneKit doesn't have anything that describes a shape in such terms, so there's no super simple answer here.

The shader modifier solution @HalMueller alludes to is interesting, but problematic. It's simple to use a modifier at the geometry entry point to make a simple bend — say, offset every y coordinate by some amount, even by an amount that's a function of why. But that's a one-dimensional transform, so you can't use it to wrap a wire around on itself. (It also changes the cross section.) And on top of that, shader modifiers happen on the GPU at render time, so their effects are an illusion: the "real" geometry in SceneKit's model is still a cylinder, so features like hit testing apply to that and not to the transformed geometry.

The best solution to making something like a helix is probably custom geometry — generating your own vertex data (`SCNGeometrySource`). The math for finding the set of points on a helix is pretty simple if you follow that shape's [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix). To wrap a cross section around it, follow the [Frenet formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) to create a local coordinate frame at each point on the helix. Then make an index buffer (`SCNGeometryElement`) to stitch all those points into a surface with triangles or tristrips. (Okay, that's a lot of hand-waving around a deep topic, but a full tutorial is too big for an SO answer. This should be enough of a breadcrumb to get started, though...)

Comment: Most excellent answer. That point about the hit testing is especially interesting and something I never would have considered.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some starting points that might help.

One approach would be to use more cylinders and make them shorter. That's the same idea behind the various `segmentCount` properties on the SCNGeometry primitives. Can we see a screenshot of the current linked cylinders version?

If you increase the `heightSegmentCount`, you could use the approach outlined here: [scenekit, how to bend an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307900/scenekit-how-to-bend-an-object/34413536#34413536).

I just took a look at SCNShape. I was thinking you could use a shader modifier to warp the extruded shape into a circular cross section. But SCNShape doesn't seem to expose a segment count property, which I think you'd need to create enough extrusion segments for a good look. The `chamferRadius` and `chamferProfile` properties look interesting. I wonder if you could use those to create an extrusion that looks good.